# MediaWiki: search for a sub-category in category (case-insensitive!)

Tags: api, search, mediawiki, categories

I'm trying to make search for composer in International Music Score Library Project (IMSLP.org).

IMSLP's wiki have a category Composers (http://imslp.org/index.php?title=Category:Composers) with about 4665 sub-categories. One sub-category - one composer.

Is it possible to make search for a sub-category in category (case-insencetive!)

I'd read about mediawiki's api and make list-request:
http://imslp.org/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Composers&cmlimit=100
It is exactly what i want, but how to implement server-side search on this result (or make other conditions in request).

Comment: You might use search as a generator, and check whether the found cats are in the expected category:

[generator=search&prop=categories&gsrnamespace=14&clcategories=Category%3AComposers&cmtitle=Category%3AComposers&gsrsearch=...](http://imslp.org/api.php?action=query&generator=search&prop=categories&gsrnamespace=14&clcategories=Category%3AComposers&cmtitle=Category%3AComposers&gsrsearch=traditional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the API server-side.

Try using something like this:

```
$api = new ApiMain(new FauxRequest($params));
$api->execute();
$res = $api->getResultData();
```

`FauxRequest` takes an array with query parameters.

Comment: What mediawiki API are for using search in category?